# What is the meaning of “peer chaincode install -p" in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I passed "first-network", no problem.

In CLI:`/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer:`, execute these commands:

```
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls true --cafile $ORDERER_CA -C mychannel -n mycc -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a","100","b","200"]}' -P "AND('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"
peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050  --tls true --cafile $ORDERER_CA -C mychannel -n mycc -c '{"Args":["invoke","a","b","10"]}' --peerAddresses peer0.org2.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
```

There are no problem. But when I execute these commands in the subdirectory of the peer `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts:`, `install`、`instantiate` and `query` success, but `invoke` error:

`Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"cannot retrieve package for chaincode mycc/1.0, error open /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/mycc.1.0: no such file or directory"`.

This happens when CLI connects to peer0.ogr1, but I find this file at peer0.ogr1:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCVIY.png)

I replaced the peer node through the CLI, and the same problem occurred under the same path.

The problem may arise from the path specified by `chaincode install -p`. The official document says that this is a path relative to `$GOPATH/src`, so I feel that this path should have nothing to do with the current directory.

After searching, I found two similar problems, but the reasons are completely different and cannot be used for reference. Therefore, I can only raise new problems and hope to find solutions.

two similar problems:

[Install a different version of chaincode (Hyperledger fabic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60754378/install-a-different-version-of-chaincode-hyperledger-fabic)

[Hyperledger Fabric - How to limit Org2 to install/instantiate/upgrade the chaincode to the channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55133710/hyperledger-fabric-how-to-limit-org2-to-install-instantiate-upgrade-the-chainc)

version: Fabric1.4.4, Ubuntu18.04

structure: one order, four peers, each distributed on five machines, there is no problem with normal transactions

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You're supposed to provide path during instantiation as well if you're performing the operation from CLI.

Comment: Which parameter in the `instantiate`? I only find the -p parameter in the `install`.